# vue infinite loading TypeError: cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-infinite-loading

I am using vue-infinite-loading. I followed their documention. but don't understand. what are $state , $state->loaded(),$state->complete();

Below image is the error i am facing.

[image: The error i am geeting]

```
    fetchReviews($state){
         var vm = this;
        axios.post('./fetch-reviews', {
            u_id: vm.u_id,
            params: {
            page: this.page,
    },
        })
        .then(({ data }) => {
            if (data.reviews.length) {
            this.page += 1;
            this.list.push(...data.reviews);
            $state.loaded();
            } else {
            $state.complete();
            }
        });

    },
```

Comment: $state is vuex state variable.Refer this https://vuex.vuejs.org/.

Comment: @riddhi can you please explain why i am getitng this error?

Comment: Yes because may be you have not integrated vuex store with your project and still you are using $state that is a store variable.

Comment: I did. Here is Initialization of vuex in app.js. import Vuex from 'vuex';
import StoreData from'./store.js';

Comment: Its should be `import { store } from './store'`